# SystemOpen from ScheduledTask

Tags: bugs, interoperability, scheduling

I could bet it used to work, now the following code fails 95% of times:

```
RunScheduledTask[Echo @ SystemOpen @ "https://www.wolfram.com", {1}]
```

Can you reproduce the problem? Is there a workaround?

Reproduced on V11.3, Win10 and OSX Mojave

> A support case with the identification [CASE:4177940] was created.

Comment: Wild guess: doesn's SystemOpen require an FE? Update: Yes it does, maybe the problem is related to that. I can confirm the problem BTW/

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes it does but `UsingFrontEnd` does not help. It is not really needed, you can do ``FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`SystemOpen@...`` and you will see it gets there (it returns `False` though). Weirdly, I think it was working well even in 11.3 because it was part of an app I created and no one complained so far. So maybe a recent paclet update?

Comment: It does not work in 11.1 on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: There is currently no workaround.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thanks for confirmation. It also depends on what we mean by a workaround :) Anyway, can you shed more light on what is wrong so we are aware of what else can be affected?

Comment: @Kuba the FrontEnd has an audit system.  It is used by Dynamic, the old web browser plugin, etc...  When you call something in the FE that interacts with the system, it wants to know where it came from.  `ScheduledTask`s breaks that link.  Your suggested workaround works but it assumes you have the rights to a.)  create the dialog box and b.)  have rights to run dynamics in that dialog box.  So it would be satisfactory for a lot of use cases, just not all of them.

Comment: @ihojnicki yes, I am aware, it is good enough for my use case. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a temporary fix:

```
RunScheduledTask[
  CreateDialog[
    Dynamic[SystemOpen @ "https://www.wolfram.com"; NotebookClose[]]
  ]
, {1}
]
```

`CreateDialog` seems to work so we launch it and as soon as it appears `Dynamic` runs `SystemOpen` and closes parent dialog. On faster machines you may not even notice the dialog and otherwise the browser popup will be distracting anyway.

Comment: Will `Visible->False` break this? If it does, the trick with `DynamicModule` and `Initialization` might work, too.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I wrongly assumed it will but it seems that the very first evaluation is run anyway. Thanks.